# Keeping tkinter panel active when plot is open

Tags: python, tkinter

The following program opens a two-column file and plots one column as a function of the other. The problem is that, as long as the graph window is open, the tkinter widgets are inactive. They become active again when the graph window is closed. I would like to keep the widgets active. So that, if I choose another file, I won't have to close the graph window. How can this be done? I tried to use, e.g., `top.after(10, openfile)` but, quite expectedly, the program prompts the user to choose a new file every 10 ms.

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


top = Tk.Tk()

file_name = Tk.StringVar()
f = []
m = []

def openfile():
    global opfi
    opfi = askopenfilename()

def plot():
    global opfi
    del f[:], m[:]
    with open(opfi, 'r') as file:
        for line in range(6000):
            g = file.readline().split('\t')
            field = str(g[0])
            magn = str(g[1])
            f.append(eval(field))
            m.append(eval(magn))

    plt.close()
    plt.plot(f, m, 'b')
    plt.show()


b1 = Tk.Button(top, text='Sample', command=openfile, width=10)
b1.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0)
b3 = Tk.Button(top, text='Plot', command=plot, width=6)
b3.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.0)

Tk.mainloop()
```

And this is a file sample I work with:

```
.983983186936   -0.702925299281
1.00236660232   -0.726670144435
1.02074058078   -0.75169698959
1.03909297815   -0.777209834745
1.05744133036   -0.801262179899
1.0757541608    -0.826426525054
1.09406204943   -0.852315870209
1.11235780038   -0.876239715363
1.13063106929   -0.900676560518
1.14890298837   -0.926342905673
```

Comment: `after` will not work because `plt.show()` blocks program and  `mainloop()` can't execute `after()`. As I know `plt.show()` was created only to fast display image - ie. for debugging code. If you want to have control then you can [embed plot in tk window](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html).

Comment: @Nae I've just edited my question

Comment: @Nae added another edit

Comment: @DenGor I think you need to make sure the file is read correctly.

Comment: @DenGor looks like it, but replacing it with `,` doesn't help much either, it seems to skip new lines, I think you should rather read with `readlines` method. That would help both with reading files with any number of lines and correct splitting.

Comment: @Nae alright, I am going to check the code using a different machine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications to parse the file the way I like:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


top = Tk.Tk()

file_name = Tk.StringVar()
f = []
m = []

def openfile():
    global opfi
    opfi = askopenfilename()

def plot():
    global opfi
    del f[:], m[:]
    with open(opfi, 'r') as file:
        g = file.readlines()                # to read unknown number of lines.
    for line_n, line in enumerate(g):       # make '1.00236660232   -0.726670144435\n'
        g[line_n] = line.strip().split()    # [1.00236660232, -0.726670144435]
        f.append(float(g[line_n][0]))       # 1.00236660232
        m.append(float(g[line_n][1]))       # -0.726670144435

    plt.close()
    plt.plot(f, m, 'b')
    plt.show()


b1 = Tk.Button(top, text='Sample', command=openfile, width=10)
b1.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0)
b3 = Tk.Button(top, text='Plot', command=plot, width=6)
b3.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.0)

top.mainloop()
```

The code above works for as in I can pick another sample to draw graph of while the gui is already being run, on:

```
C:\Users\user>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> tk.TkVersion
8.6
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` blocks until you close the window. This interrupts the `mainloop`, making your GUI unresponsive.

The matplotlib documentation has an [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) how to embed a plot in a Tkinter window.

Comment: thanks for the example. It can be implemented in my code. I still, however, haven't got one thing right: how can I update the plot? When the program plots a second graph, two windows appear, then three, etc. `canvas.get_tk_widget().destroy()` is not a solution as the plot is not removed from the memory.